# Basic Css Dropdown menu - Firefox bug

Tags: html, css, angularjs, dropdown, responsive

I have a current website built on an angular framework and I'm trying to create a css dropdown menu.  All seems perfect on CHrome and IE but I've ran into a hurdle while testing on Firefox.  I've searched for a few answers but nothing I've tried has fixed this little bug on Firefox.  Basically on hovering over a button, the css menu appears and when I try to move the mouse the menu disappears as soon as my cursor leaves the bounds of the button used to activate the menu.

Here's a little Example on JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4yzap1mt/3/

```css
.small-screen-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 270px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 99998;
}
.small-screen-menu-item h4 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-top: 6px;
}
.small-screen-menu-item ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.small-screen-menu-item ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.small-screen-menu a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.small-screen-menu-logout a {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.small-screen-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.navbar-header button {
  z-index: 99999;
}
.navbar-toggle:hover + .small-screen-menu {
  display: block;
}
.small-screen-menu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </button>

  <div class="small-screen-menu">
    <div class="small-screen-menu-item">
      <h4>Section 1</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a>item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>item 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-screen-menu-item">
      <h4>Section 2</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a>item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>item 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-screen-menu-item">
      <h4>Section 3</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a>item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>item 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to try it on chrome and firefox.  A fix or alternative solution would be greatly appreciated.  I want to try and find a fix without being too disruptive to the existing code.

Comment: Step 1: Stop writing invalid HTML. You can not nest links into a button. (And neither DIVs or lists.)

Comment: I fixed it by using a slightly different method.  Answer shown in original post.

Comment: I tested in Firefox 51 and 49 and it works on windows.